# Debounce function seems to work initially but then stops

Tags: javascript

My debounce function seems to work as expected at first.  I can see this because it appends 30 new elements with the inner text of `new-el-1` . Triggering the scroll condition again seems to block it for the length of the debounce delay but then it seems to catch up and I see tons of li elements with text all the way up to 30 ( `new-el-30` )...almost as if they were queued up waiting to fire.

```
    function fetchNewElements() {
        let i = 0;
        return function() {
            i += 1;

            let doc = document.querySelector('.container');
            for (let x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
                let newEl = document.createElement('li');
                newEl.innerText = `new-el-${i}`
                newEl.classList.add("newone");
                doc.appendChild(newEl)
            }
        }
    }

    function debounce(fn, delay) {
        let timeoutId; 

        return function(...args) {
            if (timeoutId) {
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            }

            timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                fn(...args)
            }, delay)
        } 
    }

    function checkScrollPosition(evt) {
        let reachedBottom = window.scrollY + window.pageYOffset >= document.body.offsetHeight;
        if (reachedBottom) {
            debounce(newFetch, 2000)();
        }
    }

    let newFetch = fetchNewElements();
    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScrollPosition);
```

Comment: I think you should be debouncing `checkScrollPosition`, not `newFetch`

Comment: If you generate a new debounced function at every call, it will never debounce anything. You need to instantiate it once and always call the same returned debounced function, otherwise you are just adding a timeout to all your calls. The timeoutId is lost and clearTimeout is never called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function looks fine, you're just using it wrong. You're creating a new instance of your debounced function on every scroll, rather than just creating one instance and reusing it.

This leads to multiple timeouts being created rather than a single one that is cleared and re-used.

```
// Create a single debounced function
const newFetchDebounced = debounce(newFetch, 2000);

function checkScrollPosition(evt) {
    let reachedBottom = window.scrollY + window.pageYOffset >= document.body.offsetHeight;
    if (reachedBottom) {
        newFetchDebounced();
    }
}
```

You can see why this works by adding a log inside `debounce` and seeing how many times it is called - each time it is called a new timeout is created and is not related to the old one anymore.

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
    console.log("New debounced instance created!");
    let timeoutId; 

    return function(...args) {
        if (timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }

        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            fn(...args)
        }, delay)
    } 
}
```

If you keep the log in for your usage vs my usage, mine will only log once while yours will be logged over and over again on every scroll.